# Finding the maximum without calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given that $x+y=6$. Is there any way to find the maximum value of $x^2y$ without using calculus or graphical method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does not exist! Try $y\rightarrow+\infty$.

For non-negative variables we can use AM-GM:
$$x^2y=\frac{1}{2}x\cdot x\cdot2y\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x+x+2y}{3}\right)^3=32.$$
The equality occurs for $x=4$ and $y=2$, which says that $32$ is a maximal value.

Comment: Can I know what your meaning of does not exist?

Comment: @Mathxx It means $x^2y\rightarrow+\infty$ for $y\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: He means that you need to add that $x$ and $y$ are non negative to your hypothesis.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  How do you know the equality happens at that value?

Comment: @Mathxx Substitute $x=4$ and $y=2$: $x+y=6$ and $x^2y=4^2\cdot2=32$.